# Creating an MS Certificate Authority using CA Root Certificate created with OpenSSL

Tags: ssl, openssl, certificate-authority, ad-certificate-services

Using the guide here:

http://www.davidpashley.com/articles/cert-authority.html

I have create a certificate authority using OpenSSL.  However I would now like to use the Microsoft CA instead.

The question is, is it possible to "import" the root/sub certificates I created with OpenSSL into MSCA?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

During the installation of Windows certificate services, the installer asks if you want to create a new key pair or use an existing one from before. If you are able to export the private/public key pair as a pfx file from your old CAs you should be able to use them as the new identity when creating the Windows based PKI infrastructure.

Comment: Is it also possible to import any certificates that have been issued by the old CA?

Comment: No you cant import from 3rd party product's issued certs database to Windows.